# Autofill adjacent column from based on header value

Tags: google-sheets

I have some monthly data that is running across a sheet that looks a bit like the below -

```
Item    Sep-15  Item    Oct-15  Item    Nov-15
SKU1    23  SKU1    43  SKU1    22
SKU2    43  SKU2    32  SKU2    34
SKU3    34  SKU3    44  SKU3    36
SKU4    32  SKU4    24  SKU4    45
```

As I want to run a query over the data I need to transpose the data from the three 'groups' of columns to one single column. I can do that fine with item and quantity data using query({A:A;C:C;E:E},"select * etc.

What I am trying to also do is bring the value data heading and create a 3rd column so that the data looks like this -

```
SKU1    23  Sep-15
SKU2    43  Sep-15
SKU3    34  Sep-15
SKU4    32  Sep-15
SKU1    43  Oct-15
SKU2    32  Oct-15
SKU3    44  Oct-15
SKU4    24  Oct-15
SKU1    22  Nov-15
SKU2    34  Nov-15
SKU3    36  Nov-15
SKU4    45  Nov-15
```

Any ideas on what combination of functions I can use to populate those date values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repeat the dates without using REPT (because of it's inherent limitations --> the maximum number of repetitions is 100) you could try:

```
=ArrayFormula({regexreplace(to_text(G3:G11), "\d+", G2&""); regexreplace(to_text(K3:K11), "\d+", K2&""); regexreplace(to_text(O3:O11), "\d+", O2&""); regexreplace(to_text(S3:S11), "\d+", S2&"")}+0)
```

Note: In the above I assume

- the dates to be in G2, K2, O2 and S2
- the data starting in row 3 to 11 (change to suit).